# How to change innerHTML of CRM form in MS Dynamics CRM 2015 form?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a form in MS CRM 2015 Online. it was updated to 2015 from 2013 recently.
I have a requirement such that i have to show multi select check boxes on CRM form. In CRM 2013 i have an option set with some options, with those options i am forming HTML with check boxes using script and am changing HTML.
In CRM 2013 i had changed form UI using document.getelemntByID("#element").innerHTML.

but in CRM 2015 javascript is not working. i am unable to get element using doument.getelementbyID.

I am unable to find alternative for this requirement. can any one of suggest me on this?

Comment: A two-options attribute per each checkbox is the only way to do it in a "supported" way

Comment: @Alex. Thank you for your response. can you please explain me in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those JavaScript commands are not supported by CRM and shouldn't be used.

To do this I would suggest building a web resource and embedding on the page. Then you have full control.

Comment: can you provide me any example? which kind of web resource i need to use?

Comment: A HTML web resource, http://nishantrana.me/2011/10/31/using-html-web-resource-in-crm-2011/

Comment: can i get all the data provided in html web resource in on save function?

Comment: This is not working in CRM 2015 online. basically javascript is not working.

Comment: This is working fine. 

I was using <body onload="ConvertDropDownToCheckBoxList();">, it is not working.

instead now i am using window.onload, this is working fine.

Thanks a lot boss!!! :)